# Different Results in IBM Data Studio vs RazorSQL When connecting to DB2 Server

Tags: sql, select, db2

I am getting the following results in IBM Data Studio

```
 ItemNumber                       Description                                                    Price
 0xf3f5f4f2f4f8404040404040404040 0xc8c1d9d5c5e2e260e2d7d940c3e3d9d360e2c1c360d7d3c360d5c5e3c140 4841.000
```

When I run the same query in RazorSQL I get the following results:

```
ItemNumber         Description                       Price
354248             HARNESS-SPR CTRL-SAC-PLC-NETA     4841.000
```

How do I make IBM Data Studio give the same results as RazorSQL?

Comment: Edit your question to give more details, such as the SQL (presumably the same SQL for both GUI tools), the datatype of the columns ItemNumber and Description in Db2, and which Db2-server-platform (z/os, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windws).  Also confirm (I assume) that RazorSQL and DataStudio are pointing at exactly the same database and schema.   Remember also to ensure you have the latest DataStudio version (4.1.3) with APAR-5 applied, as many bugs are fixed since v4.1.3 was issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that the data is in EBCDIC....

The real problem is that the fields are tagged with CCSID 65535 (binary) instead of CCSID 37.

CCSID 65535 tells the system not to convert the data.

RazorSQL is apparently configured to automatically convert 65535 data.  I don't have IBM data studio installed, but the "Run SQL Scripts" component of IBM ACS I use to connect to an IBM i has the following in it's JDBC config:
[image]

This setting surfaces the following property of the JDBC driver
[image]

The "right" answer is to properly tag your data with it's actual CCSID.

Comment: adding "translate binary=true" to my JDBC connection string accomplished this for me!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I need to use a cast on the non-decimal fields in Data Studio because the table is EBCDIC. So the query that works is;

```
SELECT CAST(AMFLIB7.ITMRVA.ITNBR as CHAR(16) ccsid 37) AS "ItemNumber", CAST(AMFLIB7.ITMRVA.ITDSC as CHAR(64) ccsid 37) AS "Description", AMFLIB7.ITRBPR.BZANVA As "Price" 
FROM AMFLIB7.ITMRVA
INNER JOIN AMFLIB7.ITRBPR ON AMFLIB7.ITRBPR.ITNBR = AMFLIB7.ITMRVA.ITNBR
WHERE AMFLIB7.ITMRVA.ITNBR = '354248'
ORDER BY AMFLIB7.ITRBPR.BZBLDT DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

UPDATE: Using Charles' Answer, I added "translate binary=true" to my connection string and don't have to use CAST on my queries anymore!!